# Combine same attributes with different slug - Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, shopify, code-snippets

I have multiple product attributes with the same name and same terms but different slugs. That's a result of a migration from Shopify to Woocommerce. For example, attribute 'Μέγεθος'(*'Size' in Greek*) entered 2000 times for each product. Now i don't know how to combine those to one attribute with all terms like S,M,L,XL,44,45,56 etc.

Unless i edit product attributes one by one, is there a most sufficient option? Any suggestion?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YbZdS.png)

Comment: Screenshots are not a good foundation for a [mcve]. Show sample arrays as `var_export()` text, then show us your coding attempt, then show us your exact desired result.

Comment: You can do it by exporting all products to CSV, then rename all the attributes to the same name and reimport

Comment: Try this free [woocommerce product import plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/product-import-export-for-woo/)

Comment: If we talk about variable products its a bit tricky. Your best bet would be with sql or if you have expiriance with csv you can do it this way as mention.